# Android emulator unable to consume web service throwing com.android.volley.NoConnectionError

Tags: android

Android emulator unable to consume web service ? throwing com.android.volley.NoConnectionError. How to fix this ?

i have added the internet permissions. i am having doubt about HTTP and HTTPS web service URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to this is that install the SSL (Secure Socket Layer) certificate at server end then no need to set any Charles proxy.

Every enterprise has two development environments,

1.Development ( http ) : doesn't need any SSL certificate

2.Production ( https ) : needs SSL certificate

When production environment installs the SSL certificate then android emulator and Volley library automatically detects the network connection and your were able to consume the apis/web services as expected.

Another solution to this problem is that use "Charles Proxy"